# How do i get the mouse position?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

-edit- I dont need the answer anymore now that i calculate based on mousedown position.

Basically in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725610/weird-location-while-moving-picbox-in-c-net) It seems like e.X,y and e.Location.X,Y is relative to mousedown? I seen negative values when i havent moved it left/above the parent picbox.

So it seems like the values are relative to my mousedown, but i need values relative to the parent because i update the left/top every event and other datat and relative to mousedown is breaking my code.

Comment: Since you put "C#" and ".NET" in the tags, it's not necessary to put them in the title as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725610/weird-location-while-moving-winforms-picbox

Comment: @Henk: I notice you 'close as duplicate' Note that this one is a howto question and the other is a why is this happening question. I rather the other be closed then this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do this ( assuming your control is named picbox )

```
Point pt = picbox.PointToClient(point)
```